# How can we automate social login scenarios in regression suite?

Tags: automated-testing

We have to automate an e-commerce portal that supports social login using various social providers like Google, Twitter, Linkedin, Apple, etc.

Most of these social login service providers either ask to enter CAPTCHA or ask for OTP verification or other authentication code for verification.

So how can we cover these scenarios in API automation (without being blocked by these providers after a few attempts)?

Any input would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if anything can be done about the CAPTCHA required by the Social Login service provider.

Since that bit isn't in your control, you can't even ask developers to turn off CAPTCHA for testing purpose.

Maybe you can do something about the OTP though. If it is an email based OTP service, you can automate the email retrieval and reading bit to get the OTP required to proceed further. For this you can either use API of the email service provider or you can scrape the email or can incorporate UI automation into your automation framework to read the emails via a browser and get the OTP. Selenium can help with the last part.